# Error Checking with scanf

Tags: c, error-handling, runtime-error, scanf

For my assignment, the user inputs 5 integers between 1 and 9 to represent five, 9-sided dice rolls, which are then used to calculate a score. We also need to be able to detect and invalid input, i.e. anything other than 5 integers between 1-9. The problem is that when I run the automatic test for my task, i get a runtime error when the input is less than 5 things.

My error checking code is (Ignore the countArray thing, that's for later on in the program):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

#define ARRAY_SIZE 5

...

int main(void) {

    int numbers[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int scanFail = 0;

    int i = 0;

      ...

      // Check for if 5 integers between 1 and 9 have been entered

    while (i < ARRAY_SIZE && scanFail == FALSE) {

        if (scanf("%d", &numbers[i]) != 1) {
            scanFail = TRUE;
        }

        if (numbers[i] < 1 || numbers[i] > 9) {
            scanFail = TRUE;
        }

        countArray[i] = ARRAY_NOT_COUNTED;
        i++;

    }

    if (scanFail == TRUE) {
        printf("Invalid Input: 5 integers 1..9 must be supplied.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    ...
```

This is what the autotest says:

```
  Test10 (1 2 3) - failed (errors)

  Your program produced these errors:

  Runtime error: uninitialized variable accessed.

  Execution stopped here in main() in youChew.c at line 65:

  \t\t}
  \t\t
  -->\t\t if (numbers[i] < 1 || numbers[i] > 9) {
  \t\t    scanFail = TRUE;
  \t\t}

  Values when execution stopped:

  i = 3
  numbers = {1, 2, 3, 69513217, -22336628}
  scanFail = 1
  numbers[i] = 69513217

  Test 11 (potato) - failed (errors)

  Your program produced these errors:

  Runtime error: uninitialized variable accessed.

  Execution stopped here in main() in youChew.c at line 65:

  \t\t}
  \t\t
  -->\t\t if (numbers[i] < 1 || numbers[i] > 9) {
  \t\t    scanFail = TRUE;
  \t\t}

  Values when execution stopped:

  i = 0
  numbers = {69515968, 0, 8192, 69513217, -18240628}
  scanFail = 1
  numbers[i] = 69515968
```

I'm not really sure what to do for fixing it so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is `i` initialized?

Comment: whoops my bad, forgot to put that in, it is initialised though

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem... I run the code and it waits until it gets 5 elements.

Comment: Yea thats what happens when I try to reproduce it as well, but the autotest keeps coming up with that

Comment: What input is the autotest providing?

Comment: first one is 1 2 3, and then the second is potato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO immediately breaking the loop usually produces more readable code than maintaining flags..

In your case the problem is that if scanf fails, you haven't read the number, yet you want to check whether it (the uninitialized value) is between 1 and 9. That test shouldn't even happen. *Fail fast*.

Comment: So put break statments after both the scanfail = TRUE?

Comment: I would put the whole reading procedure in a separate function and immediately return failure in those cases. Boolean flag removed.